# Can I use Next.js Link to navigate from slug page to the default one?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

So I have the default page and some 'slug' dynamic pages, the urls look like this:

default page locally: `localhost:3000/doc/default`

slug page locally: `localhost:3000/doc/[slug]`

default page in production: `default.com/doc`

slug page in production: `[slug].default.com/doc`

The link I need should be inside the slug pages and lead to the default one. So far I tried getting the `basePath` from `nextRouter` to use as a `href`. But that returns the slug url (`[slug].default.com/doc`.

Can I use the Next.js `Link` component and point it to `/doc/default`? It works locally, but I don't want to push it to `dev/prod` just to test if it works.

Comment: Could I ask why you need different routes local and production ? 
Wouldn't it be easier to just modify your local to match instead ? It seems here you are looking at domain for production. An example would be local to have local.default.com:3000/doc ( this would avoid the issue )

Comment: just wanted to ask the exact same. that would be way more easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `redirects`?

Next.js has <s>an experimental</s> a feature to redirect pages ahead of time inside its `next.config.js` file.

Let's say we'd like to redirect our root path `site.com/` to `site.com/en-us/`. We could use `useRouter` whenever we needed to redirect the user or we could add directly into `next.config.js`:

```js
const nextConfig = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        permanent: false,
        destination: '/en-us',
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Now anytime the user navigates to `site.com/` he'll be redirected to `site.com/en-us/` which will render the page inside `pages/en-us/index.(jsx|tsx|mdx)`. It is also possible to use RegEx for matching as described on [this issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/15712#issuecomment-666676618).

For your use case, would be the the other way around. We'd probably have to use absolute paths, since we're redirecting to another domain. In this case, a subdomain of our root `default.com` domain.

```
// const getSlugs = fs.readdir(path.resolve(...), () => {})
const slugs = ['slug1', 'slug2']

const slugRedirects = slugs.map(slug => ({ 
  source: `/doc/${slug}`,
  destination: `https://${slug}.default.com/doc`,
  permanent: false
}))

const nextConfig = {
  async redirects () {
    return [...slugRedirects]
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Now, whenever the user navigates to `www.default.com/doc/slug1`, either by typing the URL or clicking on a button that points to the `pages/doc/[slug]` pages, he will be redirected to `slug1.default.com/doc`.

Let me know if that helps. Cheers!

Comment: Looks like exactly what I need, I'll give it a try and come back with the result, thanks!